# How can delete a binary tree node with all possibility?

Tags: c, binary-tree

I created a binary tree with some integer values, I can search the tree by my code. But I don't know how to proceed delete node operation.

So, how can I delete a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia entry - [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) - explains how to implement BST operations.

[Deletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary%5Fsearch%5Ftree#Deletion): 
There are several cases to be considered:

- Deleting a leaf: Deleting a node with
  no children is easy, as we can simply
  remove it from the tree.
- Deleting a node with one child: Delete it and replace it with its child.
- Deleting a node with two children: Call the node to be deleted "N". Do not delete N. Instead, choose either its in-order successor node or its in-order predecessor node, "R". Replace the value of N with the value of R, then delete R. (Note: R itself has up to one child.)